# Get PHP variabile in div from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have this code in default.php:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    var $from = jQuery("#from"),
      $to = jQuery("#to");

    $from.datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: 1,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        $to.datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
      }
    });

    $from.change(function() {

      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?option=com_vehiclemanager&task=default2',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          datepicker_value: $(this).val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
        }
      });
    });

    ...
```

This is the php script:

```
<?php

$database = JFactory::getDBO();

$datepicker_value = isset($_POST['datepicker_value']) ? $_POST['datepicker_value'] : NULL;  
$month = date("m",strtotime($datepicker_value));

  $selectstring = "SELECT * FROM #__vehiclemanager_rent_sal WHERE fk_vehiclesid = 128 AND monthW = '$month'";
  $database->setQuery($selectstring);
  $string = $database->loadObject(); 


header('Content-Type: application/json');
$array[] = array(
'deposito'=>$string->deposit, 
'spese'=>$string->cfee,
);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

I have a jquery datepicker in a table and i want to pick the variable from the php script via a database query with an ajax call, i can see the json object `[{"deposito":"300","spese":"100"}]`
but the single php variabile shows me undefined.
I inserted the task in the ajax url because the filename sends me back to the index.php, the homepage, as this is an external plugin.
I hope I explained myself and thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not necessary: `jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery(function ($) {` - THIS - `$(function() {...` is enough

Comment: @mplungjan Unless `$` is overwritten by another library, it is effectively the same.

Comment: It is almost never and if it is, then the method is https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: `$(this)` reffers to the event, document ready. Do `datepicker_value: [from, to]` instead and remove `$` from `$from` and `$to`, prepend `var` instead.

Comment: @mplungjan Take a good look at `jQuery(function ($) {`, by definition the `$` already overwritten in the function, but yes you are correct but I've learned never to assume.

Comment: @Xorifelse notice the use of jQuery inside the supposedly protected $ thing. OP is just copypasting stuff - possibly from w3fools

Comment: You need to use `onSelect: function(dateText) {` instead of `$from.change` and then you have the value in dateText

Comment: Probably I didn't explain well, i want to take the "deposito" value or "spese" value and put it in div "result".
I tried with data.deposito or data[0].deposito but it shows as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(this).val()`, try referencing the actual element. Something like this: `$('#from').val()`.